# How to have better structure in my webscraping output

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

Here's my script :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait  
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

PATH = "chromedriver.exe"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH,options=options)

url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/Lazeo+Paris+11e/@48.8532051,2.3859464,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x47e6738875606957:0xdfb3822564e33888!8m2!3d48.8532051!4d2.3881404'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/span[1]/span/span/span[2]/span[1]/button').click()
#to make sure content is fully loaded we can use time.sleep() after navigating to each page
import time
time.sleep(3)


SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 5

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

number = 0

while True:
    number = number+1

    # Scroll down to bottom
    
    ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]')
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollBy(0, 5000);', ele)

    # Wait to load page

    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    print(f'last height: {last_height}')

    ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]')

    new_height = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollHeight", ele)

    print(f'new height: {new_height}')

    if number == 2:
        break

    #if new_height == last_height:
     #   break

    print('cont')
    last_height = new_height



item = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[10]')

time.sleep(3)

name_list = []
stars_list = []
review_list = []
duration_list = []


for i in item:

    button = i.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')
    for m in button:
        if m.text == "More":
            m.click()
    time.sleep(5)

    name = i.find_elements_by_class_name("d4r55")
    stars = i.find_elements_by_class_name("kvMYJc")

    review = i.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='wiI7pd']")

    duration = i.find_elements_by_class_name("rsqaWe")

    for j,k,l,p in zip(name,stars, review, duration):
        name_list.append(j.text)
        stars_list.append(p.text)
        review_list.append(k.text.strip())
        duration_list.append(l.text)



review = pd.DataFrame(
    {'name': name_list,
     'rating': stars_list,
     'review': review_list,
     'duration': duration_list})

review.to_csv('google_review.csv',index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
print(review)

driver.quit()
```

But sometimes the format of the review is not convenient, like that (sorry it's in french) :

[image: output]

That's this one on google map :

[image: html]

How to avoid that ? Because it count as several rows and I cannot work with a structure like that.

I hope the fact that's in french isn't problematic to understand the structure of the sentences.

Comment: Is it because of the new lines in the review text? you could try to remove them using k.text.strip('\n')

And you could use list comprehention to save some time: stars += [x.text.strip() for x in i.find_elements_by_class_name("kvMYJc")]

Comment: I added `k.text.strip('\n')` but it seems it doesn't work :/